# How to prevent people from Copying Text on Web Pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to prevent users from copying and pasting text from web pages through Ctrl-C Ctrl-V, or using the mouse, jQuery can anyone help??

Comment: Try this its work for control wise. http://jsfiddle.net/5TTm4/3339/

Comment: thanks Andi
it work fine

Comment: DOnt forgot to accept my answer.Please.

Answer (score 1):

Try this you can limit the controls to copy paste,with the help of jquery.

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5TTm4/3339/):

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#textbox_id').bind("cut copy paste", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
         alert("You cannot paste into this text field.");
        $('#textbox_id').bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

It could also be done with just HTML..see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/5TTm4/3349/)

```
<input type="text" onselectstart="return false" onpaste="return false;" 
    onCopy="return false" onCut="return false" onDrag="return false" 
    onDrop="return false" autocomplete=off/><br>
```

Comment: Not bad, at least it will prevent novices from doing it, and also annoy them :P

Answer (score 0):

That is simply not possible. You cannot do that. The user can disable scripts and copy what they want. For javascript solutions please use the search.

Answer (score 0):

It's not JS but might help a bit, you can use CSS to disable selection.  They could always get the text from view source or disable your css in dev tools...

```
.noselect {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```